# I can't spot the mistake in c program - Can't find the error

Tags: c, recursion, compiler-errors, function-pointers, function-definition

**This my code for finding sum of n number, I have already solved it in iteration and recursion method by tried to implement function pointer and cannot find what the error is.**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int num; 

int input(int *a)
{
    scanf("%d", a);
    return 0;
}

int sumOfNNumber(int (*number)(int*))
{
    number(&num);   
    if (num == 0) return 0;
    else  return num + sumOfNNumber(num - 1);
}

int main()
{
    sum_it = 0;
    int (*ptr)(int*) = &input;
    
    int sum_rc = sumOfNNumber(ptr);
    
    printf("%d\n", sum_rc);

    return 0;
}
```

**This is error displayed in the compiler, I used the online gdb compiler. I also tried VS Code and error persisted.**

```
main.c: In function ‘sumOfNNumber’:
main.c:24:37: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘sumOfNNumber’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
     else  return num + sumOfNNumber(num - 1);
                                     ^~~
main.c:19:5: note: expected ‘int (*)(int *)’ but argument is of type ‘int’
 int sumOfNNumber(int (*number)(int*))
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:29:5: error: ‘sum_it’ undeclared (first use in this function)
     sum_it = 0;
     ^~~~~~
main.c:29:5: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
main.c:34:25: error: ‘number’ undeclared (first use in this function)
     for(int i = 0; i <= number; i++)
                         ^~~~~~
```

**I think I have made mistake in implementing the function pointer but checked it and it correct.
Please help me to solve the by pointing out the error means and is.
Thank you.**

Comment: Read the error messages. For example what is unclear with this error message "error: ‘sum_it’ undeclared (first use in this function)"?

Comment: Sorry, its a mistake in combining fuction pointer and recursion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, to answer your primary question right away: The compiler tells it there quite clearly:

```
main.c: In function ‘sumOfNNumber’:
main.c:24:37: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘sumOfNNumber’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
     else  return num + sumOfNNumber(num - 1);
```

You invoke `sumOfNNumber` which expects a function pointer. However, what you pass is the result of an integer operation:

```
sumOfNNumber(num - 1);
```

However there is more in your code that - in my eyes - has to be addressed:

1. Using call by reference or using a global variable is not how your recursive algorithm is supposed to work. Especially given the fact, that you do not alter that value at all.
2. I don't quite understand, why you intend to use function pointers for that assignment? In fact you have a weird mixture of static recursion and usage of the function pointer. So what do you want to achieve exactly?

Maybe you want to reassess your approach in the light of those comments aswell.

Answer (score 2):

These error messages

```
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:29:5: error: ‘sum_it’ undeclared (first use in this function)
     sum_it = 0;
     ^~~~~~
main.c:29:5: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
main.c:34:25: error: ‘number’ undeclared (first use in this function)
     for(int i = 0; i <= number; i++)
                         ^~~~~~
```

mean that you are using identifiers `sum_it` and `number` before declaring them. So the compiler does not know what are types of the identifiers and as a result whether such statements like these

```
     sum_it = 0;
```

and

```
     for(int i = 0; i <= number; i++)
```

are valid.

For example in main you wrote

```
int main()
{
    sum_it = 0;
    //...
```

but the variable `sum_it` was not declared neither in main nor in the file scope. So the compiler issues an error. And moreover this identifier is never used in the program except this statement.

This error message

```
main.c: In function ‘sumOfNNumber’:
main.c:24:37: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘sumOfNNumber’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
     else  return num + sumOfNNumber(num - 1);
                                     ^~~
```

means that instead of passing as an argument a function pointer because the function `sumOfNNumbers` declared like

```
int sumOfNNumber(int (*number)(int*))
```

that is its parameter has the function pointer type `int (*number)(int*)` you are passing as an argument an integer expression `num - 1`. So again the compiler issues an error message.

If I have understood correctly you need to write a recursive function that calculates the sum of numbers entered by the user in each recursive call of the function until the user will enter zero.

If so then the function can look the following way as it is shown in the demonstrative program below.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int input( int *p )
{
    return scanf( "%d", p ) == 1 && *p != 0;
}

long long int sumOfNNumber( int ( *number )( int * ) )
{
    int n;
    
    return number( &n ) ? n + sumOfNNumber( number ) : 0;
}

int main(void) 
{
    printf( "The sum of numbers is %lld\n", sumOfNNumber( input ) );
    
    return 0;
}
```

If the user will enter the following sequence of numbers (that terminates by entereing by the user 0)

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0
```

then the program output will be

```
The sum of numbers is 45
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you even need pointers at all? There are a lot of problems with your code as described in [Vlad from Moscow's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66951297/14947044). This program should achieve what you intend to do without pointers:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

unsigned int input(void)
{
        unsigned int n;
        printf("Unsigned integer: ");
        /* check return value of `scanf` */
        if (scanf("%u", &n) != 1) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Error: invalid unsigned integer\n");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        return n;
}

unsigned int sum_up(unsigned int n)
{
    if (n <= 1)
            return 1;
    return n + sum_up(n - 1);
}

int main(void)
{
    unsigned int n = input();

    unsigned int sum = sum_up(n);
    printf("%u\n", sum);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```